# Connect a MSSQL Database with an Swift iOS App

Tags: ios, sql-server, swift, database

in our company we give our customers the possibility to create „tickets“ for support requests.
The program is written in C# and uses a MS Sql Server with an online connection possibility.

To manage the tickets we now want to implement an iOS App. I‘m very new to Swift and SwiftUI, but I have tried some tutorials.
Now I feel pretty confy that I can build this app, but I can‘t find ANY library or whatever to recieve Data of a Database-Table.
Normalwise you do that with System.Data.SqlClient or Microsoft.Data.SqlClient in C#. Are there any similar options in Swift?

(I have the Apple Developer Program so every tool I should use)

Comment: You don't want your mobile app to connect to the database directly. It should call a service (e.g. RESTful micro service), which accesses the database.